# What is the algorithm efficiency (in terms of Big-Oh) of simple fixed-size integer-arithmetic?

Tags: java, arrays, performance, algorithm, induction

For example,

```
public int sumArray()
{
  int[] arr = new int[10];

  int n = arr.length;

  int sum = (n*(n+1))/2;

  return sum;
}
```

Would the efficiency of this algorithm be O(1), O(n), or something else?

Comment: Basic arithmetic is O(1)

Comment: In this case, it's a **pure function of no arguments**, also known as a constant. Unsurprisingly, it has `O(1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Each of the individual statements in `sumArray` takes constant time (independent of the value of `n`, which is itself a constant here), so the whole function does, too.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, as I understand (offcourse if you want something official more precise, google or check wiki),

Big-O gives you an idea of how efficient is a specific algorithm like if you want to sort a list / search a element in a sorted/unsorted list, basically that require iteration with respect to size of items. As size started to become large you will see big improvement using more efficient algorithm.

In your case there is no iteration involved so this would be constant time O(1), does not really matter what the value of n is. But if you rewrote your Sigma N problem using loop from one to n and doing sum as each iteration, then it would be O(n). As you can see your solution is more efficient than loop for this particular problem. O(1) better than O(n).

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm Efficiency is O(1). There are no arguments, it's constant. You should look at the [Big-O Algorithm Complexity Cheat Sheet](http://bigocheatsheet.com/) if you get confused next time.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally assumed that the size of the basic integers is a constant, and that any machine capable of handling some number of items will inherently have a native integer size sufficient to hold that number.  Were it not for such assumptions, most algorithms would end up with an extra factor of O(lg(N)) or O(lg(N)^2) to accommodate fact that the required integer size will be O(lg(N)), and the total number of steps to perform operations on integers of size S will be O(S) or O(S*S) [in practice, most of the steps will be performed in parallel on modern hardware, but the *total* number of steps would nonetheless be O(S) or O(S*S)].

Note that these assumptions assume that code won't need to use numbers whose length exceeds O(lg(N)), but the latter assumption usually holds in practice; it's mainly necessary to prevent algorithms from using arbitrary-length integers to perform tasks that aren't O(1) in supposedly-O(1) time.